# recyclerView layout grid items not aligning properly

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

i don't know much about java, just started, so i will have difficulties understanding the answers. emli5.

screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

expected output:

[image: expected output]

in the recyclerview (right), these items are not aligning up like i want them to.

I want that each cell has a fixed size, and maximum number of columns possible in the grid.
spacing b/w each cell (both vertical and horizontal) is equal to (left space) divided by (number of columns minus one).   [with no extra space left at start, top, bottom or end]

here is the code:

```java
package com.MyStickersWA.DogeStickers;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.Formatter;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;


import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.ArrayList;

@SuppressWarnings("ALL")
public class StickerPackDetailsActivity extends AddStickerPackActivity {

    /**
     * Do not change below values of below 3 lines as this is also used by WhatsApp
     */
    public static final String EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_ID = "sticker_pack_id";
    public static final String EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_AUTHORITY = "sticker_pack_authority";
    public static final String EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_NAME = "sticker_pack_name";

    public static final String EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_WEBSITE = "sticker_pack_website";
    public static final String EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_EMAIL = "sticker_pack_email";
    public static final String EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_PRIVACY_POLICY = "sticker_pack_privacy_policy";
    public static final String EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_LICENSE_AGREEMENT = "sticker_pack_license_agreement";
    public static final String EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_TRAY_ICON = "sticker_pack_tray_icon";
    public static final String EXTRA_SHOW_UP_BUTTON = "show_up_button";
    public static final String EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_DATA = "sticker_pack";

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private GridLayoutManager layoutManager;
    private StickerPreviewAdapter stickerPreviewAdapter;
    private int numColumns;
    private View addButton;
    private View infoButton;
    private View backButton;
    private View alreadyAdded;
    private StickerPack stickerPack;
    private WhiteListCheckAsyncTask whiteListCheckAsyncTask;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sticker_pack_details);

        AdView mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        MobileAds.initialize(this, initializationStatus -> { });

        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);


        boolean showUpButton = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_SHOW_UP_BUTTON, false);
        stickerPack = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_DATA);
        TextView packNameTextView = findViewById(R.id.pack_name);
        TextView packPublisherTextView = findViewById(R.id.author);
        ImageView packTrayIcon = findViewById(R.id.tray_image);
        TextView packSizeTextView = findViewById(R.id.pack_size);
        TextView stickersQtyTextView = findViewById(R.id.stickers_qty);
        TextView stickersAnimatedView = findViewById(R.id.stickers_animated);
        ImageView stickersAnimatedImage = findViewById(R.id.sticker_pack_animation_indicator);
        SimpleDraweeView expandedStickerView = findViewById(R.id.sticker_details_expanded_sticker);

        addButton = findViewById(R.id.add_to_whatsapp_button);
        infoButton = findViewById(R.id.action_info);
        backButton = findViewById(R.id.action_back);
        alreadyAdded = findViewById(R.id.already_added_button);
        layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 1);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.sticker_list);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(pageLayoutListener);

        if (stickerPreviewAdapter == null) {
            stickerPreviewAdapter = new StickerPreviewAdapter(getLayoutInflater(), R.drawable.sticker_error, getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.sticker_pack_details_image_size), getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.sticker_pack_details_image_padding), stickerPack, expandedStickerView);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(stickerPreviewAdapter);
        }
        packNameTextView.setText(stickerPack.name);
        packPublisherTextView.setText(stickerPack.publisher);
        packTrayIcon.setImageURI(StickerPackLoader.getStickerAssetUri(stickerPack.identifier, stickerPack.trayImageFile));
        packSizeTextView.setText(Formatter.formatShortFileSize(this, stickerPack.getTotalSize()));
        stickersQtyTextView.setText(stickerPack.getTotalQty() + "");
        addButton.setOnClickListener(v -> addStickerPackToWhatsApp(stickerPack.identifier, stickerPack.name));
        infoButton.setOnClickListener(v -> onOptionsItemSelected());
        backButton.setOnClickListener(v -> finish());

        if (stickerPack.animatedStickerPack) {
            Uri animatedIcon = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"+R.drawable.animated_indicator_vector);
            stickersAnimatedImage.setImageURI(animatedIcon);
            stickersAnimatedView.setText("Animated");
        } else {
            Uri animatedIcon = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"+R.drawable.static_indicator_vector);
            stickersAnimatedImage.setImageURI(animatedIcon);
            stickersAnimatedView.setText("Static");
        }
    }


    private void launchInfoActivity(String publisherWebsite, String publisherEmail, String privacyPolicyWebsite, String licenseAgreementWebsite, String trayIconUriString) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(StickerPackDetailsActivity.this, StickerPackInfoActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(StickerPackDetailsActivity.EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_ID, stickerPack.identifier);
        intent.putExtra(StickerPackDetailsActivity.EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_WEBSITE, publisherWebsite);
        intent.putExtra(StickerPackDetailsActivity.EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_EMAIL, publisherEmail);
        intent.putExtra(StickerPackDetailsActivity.EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_PRIVACY_POLICY, privacyPolicyWebsite);
        intent.putExtra(StickerPackDetailsActivity.EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_LICENSE_AGREEMENT, licenseAgreementWebsite);
        intent.putExtra(StickerPackDetailsActivity.EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_TRAY_ICON, trayIconUriString);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected() {
        if (stickerPack != null) {
            Uri trayIconUri = StickerPackLoader.getStickerAssetUri(stickerPack.identifier, stickerPack.trayImageFile);
            launchInfoActivity(stickerPack.publisherWebsite, stickerPack.publisherEmail, stickerPack.privacyPolicyWebsite, stickerPack.licenseAgreementWebsite, trayIconUri.toString());
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    private final ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener pageLayoutListener = new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

            int imgSize = recyclerView.getContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.sticker_pack_details_image_size);
            int recyclerViewWidth = recyclerView.getWidth();

            int numColumns = recyclerViewWidth / imgSize;
            int colSpacing = (recyclerViewWidth - (numColumns * imgSize)) / (numColumns - 1);
//            int colSpacing = recyclerView.getWidth() - imgSize * numColumns;

            setNumColumns(numColumns, colSpacing);
        }
    };

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    private void setNumColumns(int numColumns, int colSpacing) {
        if (this.numColumns != numColumns) {

//            recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(4, 2, 2));
            layoutManager.setSpanCount(numColumns);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

            this.numColumns = numColumns;
            if (stickerPreviewAdapter != null) {
                stickerPreviewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        whiteListCheckAsyncTask = new WhiteListCheckAsyncTask(this);
        whiteListCheckAsyncTask.execute(stickerPack);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (whiteListCheckAsyncTask != null && !whiteListCheckAsyncTask.isCancelled()) {
            whiteListCheckAsyncTask.cancel(true);
        }
    }

    private void updateAddUI(Boolean isWhitelisted) {
        if (isWhitelisted) {
            addButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            alreadyAdded.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            addButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            alreadyAdded.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    static class WhiteListCheckAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<StickerPack, Void, Boolean> {
        private final WeakReference<StickerPackDetailsActivity> stickerPackDetailsActivityWeakReference;

        WhiteListCheckAsyncTask(StickerPackDetailsActivity stickerPackListActivity) {
            this.stickerPackDetailsActivityWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(stickerPackListActivity);
        }

        @Override
        protected final Boolean doInBackground(StickerPack... stickerPacks) {
            StickerPack stickerPack = stickerPacks[0];
            final StickerPackDetailsActivity stickerPackDetailsActivity = stickerPackDetailsActivityWeakReference.get();
            if (stickerPackDetailsActivity == null) {
                return false;
            }
            return WhitelistCheck.isWhitelisted(stickerPackDetailsActivity, stickerPack.identifier);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean isWhitelisted) {
            final StickerPackDetailsActivity stickerPackDetailsActivity = stickerPackDetailsActivityWeakReference.get();
            if (stickerPackDetailsActivity != null) {
                stickerPackDetailsActivity.updateAddUI(isWhitelisted);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```java
/*
 * Copyright (c) WhatsApp Inc. and its affiliates.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the BSD-style license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */

package com.MyStickersWA.DogeStickers;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.facebook.drawee.backends.pipeline.Fresco;
import com.facebook.drawee.interfaces.DraweeController;
import com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView;

public class StickerPreviewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StickerPreviewViewHolder> {

    private static final float COLLAPSED_STICKER_PREVIEW_BACKGROUND_ALPHA = 1f;
    private static final float EXPANDED_STICKER_PREVIEW_BACKGROUND_ALPHA = 0.2f;

    @NonNull
    private final StickerPack stickerPack;

    private final int cellSize;
    private final int cellLimit;
    private final int cellPadding;
    private final int errorResource;
    private final SimpleDraweeView expandedStickerPreview;

    private final LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private View clickedStickerPreview;
    float expandedViewLeftX;
    float expandedViewTopY;

    StickerPreviewAdapter(
            @NonNull final LayoutInflater layoutInflater,
            final int errorResource,
            final int cellSize,
            final int cellPadding,
            @NonNull final StickerPack stickerPack,
            final SimpleDraweeView expandedStickerView) {
        this.cellSize = cellSize;
        this.cellPadding = cellPadding;
        this.cellLimit = 0;
        this.layoutInflater = layoutInflater;
        this.errorResource = errorResource;
        this.stickerPack = stickerPack;
        this.expandedStickerPreview = expandedStickerView;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public StickerPreviewViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewGroup viewGroup, final int i) {
        View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.sticker_image_item, viewGroup, false);
        StickerPreviewViewHolder vh = new StickerPreviewViewHolder(itemView);

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = vh.stickerPreviewView.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.height = cellSize;
        layoutParams.width = cellSize;
        vh.stickerPreviewView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        vh.stickerPreviewView.setPadding(cellPadding, cellPadding, cellPadding, cellPadding);

        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final StickerPreviewViewHolder stickerPreviewViewHolder, final int i) {
        stickerPreviewViewHolder.stickerPreviewView.setImageResource(errorResource);
        stickerPreviewViewHolder.stickerPreviewView.setImageURI(StickerPackLoader.getStickerAssetUri(stickerPack.identifier, stickerPack.getStickers().get(i).imageFileName));
        stickerPreviewViewHolder.stickerPreviewView.setOnClickListener(v -> expandPreview(i, stickerPreviewViewHolder.stickerPreviewView));
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
        this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(hideExpandedViewScrollListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetachedFromRecyclerView(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onDetachedFromRecyclerView(recyclerView);
        recyclerView.removeOnScrollListener(hideExpandedViewScrollListener);
        this.recyclerView = null;
    }

    private final RecyclerView.OnScrollListener hideExpandedViewScrollListener =
            new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                    if (dx != 0 || dy != 0) {
                        hideExpandedStickerPreview();
                    }
                }
            };

    private void positionExpandedStickerPreview(int selectedPosition) {
        if (expandedStickerPreview != null) {
            // Calculate the view's center (x, y), then use expandedStickerPreview's height and
            // width to
            // figure out what where to position it.
            final ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams recyclerViewLayoutParams =
                    ((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) recyclerView.getLayoutParams());
            final int recyclerViewLeftMargin = recyclerViewLayoutParams.leftMargin;
            final int recyclerViewRightMargin = recyclerViewLayoutParams.rightMargin;
            final int recyclerViewWidth = recyclerView.getWidth();
            final int recyclerViewHeight = recyclerView.getHeight();

            final StickerPreviewViewHolder clickedViewHolder =
                    (StickerPreviewViewHolder)
                            recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(selectedPosition);
            if (clickedViewHolder == null) {
                hideExpandedStickerPreview();
                return;
            }
            clickedStickerPreview = clickedViewHolder.itemView;
            final float clickedViewCenterX =
                    clickedStickerPreview.getX()
                            + recyclerViewLeftMargin
                            + clickedStickerPreview.getWidth() / 2f;
            final float clickedViewCenterY =
                    clickedStickerPreview.getY() + clickedStickerPreview.getHeight() / 2f;

            expandedViewLeftX = clickedViewCenterX - expandedStickerPreview.getWidth() / 2f;
            expandedViewTopY = clickedViewCenterY - expandedStickerPreview.getHeight() / 2f;

            // If the new x or y positions are negative, anchor them to 0 to avoid clipping
            // the left side of the device and the top of the recycler view.
            expandedViewLeftX = Math.max(expandedViewLeftX, 0);
            expandedViewTopY = Math.max(expandedViewTopY, 0);

            // If the bottom or right sides are clipped, we need to move the top left positions
            // so that those sides are no longer clipped.
            final float adjustmentX =
                    Math.max(
                            expandedViewLeftX
                                    + expandedStickerPreview.getWidth()
                                    - recyclerViewWidth
                                    - recyclerViewRightMargin,
                            0);
            final float adjustmentY =
                    Math.max(expandedViewTopY + expandedStickerPreview.getHeight() - recyclerViewHeight, 0);

            expandedViewLeftX -= adjustmentX;
            expandedViewTopY -= adjustmentY;


            expandedStickerPreview.setX(expandedViewLeftX);
            expandedStickerPreview.setY(expandedViewTopY);
        }
    }

    private void expandPreview(int position, View clickedStickerPreview) {
        if (isStickerPreviewExpanded()) {
            hideExpandedStickerPreview();
            return;
        }

        this.clickedStickerPreview = clickedStickerPreview;
        if (expandedStickerPreview != null) {
            positionExpandedStickerPreview(position);

            final Uri stickerAssetUri = StickerPackLoader.getStickerAssetUri(stickerPack.identifier, stickerPack.getStickers().get(position).imageFileName);
            DraweeController controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
                    .setUri(stickerAssetUri)
                    .setAutoPlayAnimations(true)
                    .build();
            expandedStickerPreview.setImageResource(errorResource);
            expandedStickerPreview.setController(controller);

            expandedStickerPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            recyclerView.setAlpha(EXPANDED_STICKER_PREVIEW_BACKGROUND_ALPHA);

            expandedStickerPreview.setOnClickListener(v -> hideExpandedStickerPreview());
        }
    }

    public void hideExpandedStickerPreview() {
        if (isStickerPreviewExpanded() && expandedStickerPreview != null) {
            clickedStickerPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            expandedStickerPreview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            recyclerView.setAlpha(COLLAPSED_STICKER_PREVIEW_BACKGROUND_ALPHA);
        }
    }

    private boolean isStickerPreviewExpanded() {
        return expandedStickerPreview != null && expandedStickerPreview.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        int numberOfPreviewImagesInPack;
        numberOfPreviewImagesInPack = stickerPack.getStickers().size();
        if (cellLimit > 0) {
            return Math.min(numberOfPreviewImagesInPack, cellLimit);
        }
        return numberOfPreviewImagesInPack;
    }
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a custom item decoration by extending `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration`. You can do something like this:

```
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.view.View;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class GridSpacingItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

private final int numberOfColumns;
private final int spacing;
private final boolean addSpacingToPerimeter;

public GridSpacingItemDecoration(int numberOfColumns, int spacing, boolean addSpacingToPerimeter) {
    this.numberOfColumns = numberOfColumns;
    this.spacing = spacing;
    this.addSpacingToPerimeter = addSpacingToPerimeter;
}

@Override
public void getItemOffsets(@NonNull Rect outRect, @NonNull View view, RecyclerView parent, @NonNull RecyclerView.State state) {
    int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view); // item position
    int column = position % numberOfColumns; // item column

    if (addSpacingToPerimeter) {
        outRect.left = spacing - column * spacing / numberOfColumns;
        outRect.right = (column + 1) * spacing / numberOfColumns; 

        if (position < numberOfColumns) { // top edge
            outRect.top = spacing;
        }
        outRect.bottom = spacing; // item bottom
    } else {
        outRect.left = column * spacing / numberOfColumns;
        outRect.right = spacing - (column + 1) * spacing / numberOfColumns;
        if (position >= numberOfColumns) {
            outRect.top = spacing; // item top
        }
    }
}
}
```

and then use it like this

```
int numberOfColumns = 3; // 3 columns
int spacing = 50; // 50px
boolean addSpacingToPerimeter = false;
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(numberOfColumns, spacing, addSpacingToPerimeter))
```

The `GridSpacingItemDecoration` class takes as a parameter the number of columns, the spacing in pixel and a boolean value that specifies whether you want spacing to be added to the list's perimeter as well. This boolean if set to true will add the given spacing as a margin not only between the grid adapter's items, but also between the items and the whole recyclerView.

Keep in mind that spacing is in pixels. So if you want to use dp instead, you can convert dp to px using

```
Math.round(dpValue * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density))
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like every item has right padding.

You should use `addItemDecoration` on your RecyclerView instead.

Or use this: https://github.com/grzegorzojdana/SpacingItemDecoration